# Transfer apps from iPhone to MacBook Pro

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore

Is there a way to transfer the apps on my phone to my Mac?  I want to update a couple of apps but I would like to keep a copy of the previous versions in case the newer versions don't work properly. I know Apple  stopped allowing the transfer of purchases through iTunes, but I was wondering if there was any workaround available before updating. Alternatively, is there a way to transfer an older version of an app from one device to another?

iOS version: 10.3.3
iTunes version: 12.3.3.17

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have Dropbox on your Mac?

Comment: @jmh Yes, I have a Dropbox account, but I don't have the app installed -- I always use the web version.

Comment: You can use a tool such as iMazing to keep backups of applications, but you need to have already backed up the application from the App Store before the publically available version changed.  In these days of app thinning, even if you could copy the app off the phone, you wouldn't want the copy you got off the phone.